# how to import a csv file into R without comma

Tags: r

[image]

[image]

I am trying to import a csv file into R using read.table() syntax ,but the result is a data.frame separated by comma.

how can i adjust it to make it look like the image below? and how can i change the missing value into NA?

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful in this case if you would please [edit] your question to include the top few lines of this raw file into a [code block]. It seems from your use of `read.table(.., sep=",")` that something is wrong with the data in the file that would result in this.

Comment: It is the unfortunate `.` period between your headers that is causing this to be seen as a single column, read.table( with skip = 1, then go back and name your columns will perhaps ameliorate. This is to say, `,` comma is still your useful separator. Just have to step past the unwholesome header line. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: It would help to see the raw data, because it's possible that the periods in the header are a result of R replacing spaces with periods after reading the data as one column.

Comment: okay thanks for doing that! Can you include the first three lines of the file in your question?

Comment: Sure looks like some genius decided to put commas into the text strings in each cell and then save as CSV.  How is any interpreter supposed to tell the difference between a cell-separating comma and the commas inside?    Anyway, what is your `locale` ?   If you look at the CSV file with a text editor, are commas or periods the actual cell-separators?